# Clicking on auto complete page goes disappear angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am creating a single page application and using angular js.
I am using auto complete from angular material and trying to use

> md-autocomplete

instead of native select dropdown.
In HTML

```
<md-autocomplete md-no-cache="true" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-items="item in items" md-search-text="searchText" md-item-text="item">
   <span>{{ item }}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

in JS

```
$scope.items = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

[image: this is the image before click]
[image: this is after click]

Comment: Hi, You can check z-index of your dropdown modal window

Comment: Any errors in console when you type into it?

Comment: @Dev Qualwebs, This all seems OK. I even tested it in a fiddle and it worked. Please show full JS and HTML. Maybe the problem is not in this piece of code. For example, your controller may not be bound the right way.